# Couchdb views crashing for large documents

Tags: couchdb

Couchdb keeps crashing whenever I try to build the index of the views of a design document emitting values for large documents. The total size of the database is 40 MB and I guess the documents are about 5 MB each. We're talking about large JSON without any attachment.

What concerns me is that I have 2.5 GB of free ram before trying to access the views but as soon as I try to access them, the CPU usage raises to 99% and all the free RAM gets eaten by `erl.exe` before the indexing fails with exit code `1`.

Here is the log:

> [info] 2016-11-22T22:07:52.263000Z couchdb@localhost <0.212.0> -------- couch_proc_manager <0.15603.334> died normal
>
> [error] 2016-11-22T22:07:52.264000Z couchdb@localhost <0.15409.334> b9855eea74 rexi_server throw:{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}} [{couch_mrview_util,get_view,4,[{file,"src/couch_mrview_util.erl"},{line,56}]},{couch_mrview,query_view,6,[{file,"src/couch_mrview.erl"},{line,244}]},{rexi_server,init_p,3,[{file,"src/rexi_server.erl"},{line,139}]}]

Views skipping these documents can be accessed without issue. Which general guidelines could you provide me to help with this kind of situation? I am using couchdb 2.0 on windows.

Many thanks

**Update :** I tried to limit the number of view server instances to 1 and vary the max RAM allowed for couchjs, but it keeps crashing. Also I noticed that even though CouchDb is supposed to pass only one document at a time to the view server, erl.exe keeps eating all the available RAM (3GB used for three 5mb docs to update...). Initially I thought this could be because of the multiple couchjs instances but apparently this isn't the case.

**Update :** Made some progress, now it looks like the indexing is progressing well for just less than 10 minutes then erl.exe crashes. I have [posted the dump here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=39457175902042589414) (just to clarify "well" means, 99% CPU usage and computer screen completely frozen).

Comment: Tried to increase the size of couchjs using various values for ./bin/couchjs -S MAX_RAM_TO_USE_IN_BYTES ./share/server/main.js without success.

Comment: I noticed that several instances of couchjs are started when I try to access the view perhaps, is there a way to restrict the number of concurrent couchjs instances to 1 ?

Comment: So apparently the doc is wrong and the config query_server#os_process_limit is not about setting the timeout but about limiting the number of processes. Unfortunately the indexing keeps crashing even if I limit the number of processes to 1

Comment: Probably unlikely, but might it be a problem in the view? Can you post it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post it but I'm positive the problem does not come from the view